# How to restrict bitbucket access from another ip's

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-cloud

Is there any way we can restrict bitbucket access from out of office due to security purpose. We want to access bitbucket by with only our statics ip's.
Please suggest.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/blog/big-strides-cloud-security-ip-whitelisting-required-2-step-verification-bitbucket

Answer (score 3):

You've tagged this for both Bitbucket Server (the self-hosted one) and Bitbucket Cloud (bitbucket.org). The answer is wildly different for each.

For Bitbucket Server: You control where it's installed, including all network details. If you don't want some IPs to be able to access it, then use a firewall or access control list or something; the specific answer will depend on your environment but it's entirely up to you.

For Bitbucket Cloud: as CodeCaster mentioned, there is a premium feature for Bitbucket Cloud that lets you define an IP whitelist for repositories. https://bitbucket.org/blog/big-strides-cloud-security-ip-whitelisting-required-2-step-verification-bitbucket has the announcement, and https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/control-access-to-your-private-content-862621261.html has the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you please share support mail id?